# Locate numbers (or characters) after specific word in string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've seen variations of this question asked a million times but somehow can't figure out a solution for myself.

```
( PIN  700W_start_stop( STS_PROP( POS_X 1233 )( POS_Y 456 )( BIT_CNT 1 )( CNCT_ID 7071869 ))(USR_PROP( VAR 1( Var_typ  -1 )(AssocCd H12 )( termLBLttt +S)( Anorm 011.1)(Amax 1.0))
```

How do I pull out the number after 'POS_X'? i.e. 1233
I thought I had it figured out using regex because it seems extremely straightforward. But it's not working (go figure).

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df_pin = pd.DataFrame(columns = 
['ID','Pos_x','Pos_y','conn_ID','Association_Code','Anorm','Amax'])

with open(r'C:\Users\user1\Documents\Python Scripts\test1.txt', 'r', 
encoding="ISO-8859-1") as txt:

    for line in txt:
        data = txt.read()
        line = line.strip()
        x = re.search(r'POS_X (\d+)', data)
        df_pin = df_pin.append({'POS_X' : x, ignore_index = True}
        print (x)
```

Shouldn't this give me the numbers after 'POS_X' and then append it do the corresponding column in my dataframe?? There may be multiple occurrences of 'POS_X ###' on the same line, I only want to find the first. What if I wanted to do the same for 'PIN' and extract '700W_start_stop'?

Comment: You read the whole file into `data` with `data = txt.read()` and do not do anything with your `line`  after it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is this incorrect?

Comment: Well, that makes no sense. Also, the indentation is wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well I want one big string object that I can iterate through the lines of, but I am only doing one line in this example to try and figure it out.

Comment: `x.group(1)` will return the number.

Comment: @Barmar Hi, thanks for the help. When I try to run >>print(x.group(1)) I receive the following error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group''

Comment: That means there was no match, you need to check for that first.

Comment: @Barmar the data in the text file is identical to what I have posted at the beginning of my question. There by all means should be a match.

Comment: Why are you calling `txt.read()` inside the loop? You're already reading the file with `for line in txt:`. Shouldn't you be searching `line` rather than `data`?

Comment: The second time through the loop, `data` will be empty, so the regexp won't match it.

Comment: Either use `for line in txt:` or `data = txt.read()` but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.search()` returns a `MatchObject` object. `\d+` is matched by the first capture group in the regexp, so you need to use

```
if x:
    print(x.group(1))
else:
    print("POS_X not found")
```

to print that.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/NLgtaK)

The whole loop should be:

```
import re
with open(r'C:\Users\user1\Documents\Python Scripts\test1.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as txt:
    for line in txt:
        line = line.strip()
        x = re.search(r'POS_X (\d+)', line)
        if x:
            print(x.group(1))
        else:
            print("POS_X not found in", line)
```

For `PIN`, you could use:

```
x = re.search(r'PIN (\w+)')
```

`\w` matches alphanumeric characters and `_`.

Comment: I updated my code. My issue is that I get the error "expected string or bytes-like object". Is this done differently since I am reading the text in from a file?

Comment: The argument to `re.search()` should be `line`, not `txt`.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, since my answer makes no sense when the question is the same code I posted.

Comment: If you want to show what you tried, add it to the end of the question, don't remove the original code.

Comment: When changing the argument to line I just get the print out 'POS_X not found' which is just not right. This problem should be extremely easy to figure out but it just isn't working

Comment: Try putting `print(line)` first to see what the line actually contains.

Comment: The string you show is spread over multiple lines. Is that how it is in the file, or is it just one line?

Comment: It is one line, just very long

Comment: I've posted the entire script. I just tested it and it worked.

Comment: Don't understand why mine doesn't work still the same issue

Comment: Are you sure you're using `r` mode and not `rb` mode when opening the file?

Comment: Search [so] for "[python] re.search expected string or bytes" and you'll find a number of questions about this error.

Comment: I have double checked that the file is being opened properly, and I am not receiving any error, it just isn't finding the string match

Comment: I have found the problem. 'POS_X' and the number after are separated by two spaces not one.

Comment: You can use `r'POS_X\s+(\d+)'` to allow any amount of whitespace there.